# What is the most innocent, defenseless creature on the Material Plane?

Tags: dnd-5e, animals

This is most likely a silly question, but here's the backstory: A bit ago, I made a swarmkeeper ranger flavoured as *"the kindest, sweetest person you'll ever meet. A gentle woman whose childlike sense of wonder caused even the most defenseless of animals to swarm together out of an urge to protect her."* I wanted her swarm to be the last thing anyone would think could hurt them, creatures so gentle and defenseless that their determination to fight itself would pay testament to her kindness.

At the time, I settled on rabbits, thinking of them as little fluff balls with no attack power, but as I started to dive into the later game build, the more uncertain I became of my choice... that said, I feel like the options given in the subclass would also miss the mark for this build... and now I find myself at a mental block on what other options I might have...

As such, I'd like to turn to the wisdom of the forum for options: what tiny, cuddly creatures do you know of that has a 1pt attack or less, does not normally have an aggressive nature, and couldn't scare a child if it wishes to try?

Comment: Are you specifically looking for the least dangerous creature *that has a statblock*, or are you looking for the least dangerous real world animal even if it doesn't have a stat block?

Comment: Is this for the Gathered Swarm 3rd level feature? If so, this question is probably much better suited elsewhere as it has really nothing to do with the gameplay.

Comment: @NautArch Yes, it is for Gathered Swarm. I'll leave this closed and post it elsewhere.

Answer (score 5):

If you are just worried about the RAW numbers, then a ***Miniature Giant Space Hamster*** is the weakest creature in the books.

From *[Waterdeep: Dungeon of the Mad Mage p.251,](https://www.dndbeyond.com/marketplace/adventures/waterdeep-dungeon-of-the-mad-mage)* the miniature giant space hamster has the statistics of the rat, but no attacks; this means it has an AC of 10, 1 hit point, and no actions.  The only thing a space hamster is able to do that may put it above some other creatures is 30ft of dark vision, and *keen smell*.
I think it is a fair assumption that the space hamster stat block could be used for regular hamsters as well (the description of the creature even reads "The space hamster looks remarkably like a normal hamster"), if your DM does not want space/spelljamming vessels to be a factor in their campaign.

If you are thinking outside of RAW, then I would recommend thinking about creatures on earth that are always cute, regardless of a person's personal fears or past.  Frogs and Fish are weak, but people tend to be afraid of slimy things that can (occasionally) move quickly, so I would recommend sticking to mammals. The best that comes to mind is the [Quokka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quokka). Quokka have virtually no natural predators, so they are very friendly to humans (which could be extrapolated to humanoids), and are famous for there permanent smile.

Comment: Miniature giant space hamsters can be vicious...they go right for the eyes!

Comment: They *also* turn into normal Giant Space Hamsters if affected by a spell or potion of giant's growth.

Answer (score -1):

### Frogs.

Other options include mice, kittens, adorable corgi pups, female versions of any skittish 4-legged creature (deer are a good example), hedgehogs, skinks (the small house lizards).

Ultimately, most creatures will fight, even pointlessly, on the off-chance they can escape a predator.  In weird circumstances, even usually harmless-to-humans creatures like storks or fish or hedgehogs can end up being someone's doom (often involving them getting startled and falling off or down something).  To show something is a lovely, helpful animal, you should do so via description.  A golden retriever has fangs but if you describe one bounding joyfully up to the party with a well brushed coat carrying a stick they can throw so it can fetch, it turning on them will be far scarier.  That principle applies here - the description is what will sell this.

Comment: Is this just your opinion or is it based on something from the rules?

Comment: I think the mechanical argument may be that the Frog is one of the very few creatures in the MM that has a statblock without attack action (or any action, really), befitting a classical target form for baleful polymorph (although the other contender, the Seahorse, is even better suited, as it has no movement on land). For a cute, cuddly creature however, I agree it is not a great fit. A cute mouse or mole or if you can chose an age, poult or baby cat would seem a better fit.